# Using ORD_MAP as a hash table in SML/NJ

Tags: hashmap, structure, signature, smlnj

I'm trying to implement something similar to a hash table in ML, but i want to use lists as keys. I think I could use the ORD_MAP structure, but I want to provide my own structure for the ORD_KEY signature, so that I can use lists as ord_keys, but I cant find a way to do it. How could it be done?

Answer (score 4):

ORD_MAP and ORD_KEY are signatures. If you want to be able to use a map, you'll need a specific implementation. For example:

```
structure Key =
  struct
    type ord_key = int
    val compare = Int.compare
  end
structure Map = RedBlackMapFn (Key)
```

Then, you can do:

```
  - Map.singleton (1, "foo");
   val it = - : string map
   - Map.find (it, 1);
   val it = SOME "foo" : string option
   -
```

Hope that helps! The documentation on these interfaces is:
http://www.smlnj.org/doc/smlnj-lib/Manual/toc.html

Answer (score 0):

An example that I think answers your question lies at  cornell's university lecture here: 
[Cornell's Lecture](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs312/2008sp/handouts/sml-nj-library.html)